# Can you set attached properties for an anonymous type in an object initializer?

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

Let's say I want to add a border with a light blue color to a cell in a Grid without naming it:

```
MyGrid.Children.Add(new Border() {
   BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightBlue),
});
```

Since I didn't call Grid.SetRow and Grid.SetColumn the Border will appear at cell 0,0 which is not always what I want. I'd like to be able to call SetRow and SetColumn inside the object initializer for the Border as I did for the BorderBrush. Is there way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 - delete all that and use proper XAML. 2 - I don't see an anonymous type anywhere in your code. What are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in nomenclature. No, XAML isn't the best solution in all situations. Even Microsoft implicitly agrees or they wouldn't have provided programmatic options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You have to assign the `Border` to a variable and call `SetRow`/`SetColumn` on it.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid so.